# How to go back to a certain point in the code

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming.

I just want to know if there is any way to go back to a certain point in the code without using a `while` or a `do-while` loop.

Here is an example:

```
int a; 

cout << "What's 2+2?";
cin >> a;
if (a==4) {cout << "Nice!";}
else {cout << "WRONG! Try again!";}
```

So, if the player fails, I want to ask the question again, so going back to:

> cout << "What's 2+2?";

Is there any way to do it without using a loop?

Comment: You could use a `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to repeat something until a condition is satisfied.  That is the definition of a loop, and there are many ways to write loops in C++.  The example you showed is best handled using a `do-while` loop:

```
int a; 

do
{
    cout << "What's 2+2?";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 4) {
        cout << "Nice!";
        break;
    }

    cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
}
while (true);
```

Though you could use a `while` or `for` loop instead:

```
int a; 

while (true)
{
    cout << "What's 2+2?";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 4) {
        cout << "Nice!";
        break;
    }

    cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
}
```

```
int a; 

for(;;)
{
    cout << "What's 2+2?";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 4) {
        cout << "Nice!";
        break;
    }

    cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
}
```

That being said, to answer your actual question, you can use a `goto` statement without any other looping instructions:

```
int a; 

askTheUser:

cout << "What's 2+2?";
cin >> a;

if (a != 4) {
    cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
    goto askTheUser;
}

cout << "Nice!";
```

But, `goto` is rarely used in modern coding, it is not likely to perform any better than a `do-while` loop after compiler optimizations are applied, and it has limitations on how it can be used.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you say `do-while` is the best-fitting solution - I always found popular opinion to be that `while` loops are usually more readable and intuitive, and this situation doesn't have logic that makes it messy to force the loop to always execute at least once.

Comment: A `while` (and `for`) loop evaluates its condition before the first iteration is run, which is a waste of CPU time if the condition is always true initially. Those loops are intended for running 0+ iterations. A `do-while` loop delays the evaluation until after the first iteration is finished. It is intended for running 1+ iterations. And besides, an optimizing compiler that is smart enough to recognize the initial condition is always true is likely to rework a `while` loop into a `do-while` loop, so it is best to just be explicit about it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know about the goto. It seems like it's the best fitting for my scenario (which is not the one that I wrote; that was just an example).

Comment: @FrankZ. Be careful with the `goto`. While it is sometimes the correct choice, that sometimes comes very rarely, and even on those rare occasions you will have to deal with raised eyebrows and occasionally screaming hordes of anti-`goto` fanatics. Quite often what looks like a job for `goto` is actually a better job for a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
DontDoThis:
...
goto DontDoThis;
```

That's it.

`DontDoThis:` is a "label", and `goto DontDoThis` jumps execution to the specified label. But, like the label's name says, DONT DO THIS!  Using `goto` is concerned bad practice in modern coding, there are better ways to handle looping.

You should initialize `a` to 0 and then use a `while (a != 4)` loop.  But that's not your question :)

Answer (score 1):

The preferred language construct for executing a block of code more than once is a loop, which can be of a `for`, a `do-while`, or a `while` form.
So I'd write the code as follows:

```
int a;
bool correctGuess = false;

while (!correctGuess) {
  cout << "What's 2+2?";
  cin >> a;
  if (a==4) {cout << "Nice!"; correctGuess = true; }
  else { cout << "WRONG! Try again!"; }
}
```

Another way would be the use of recursion, i.e. a function that calls itself until a particular condition is met. Yet this seems to be a to complicated approach for your scenario.

If - for any reason - you are asked to not use such kind of loops, you could use a `goto`-statement (though this is clearly not the preferred way to do; `goto`-statements are very rarely used nowadays):

```
   int a;

loop:
   cout << "What's 2+2?";
   cin >> a;
   if (a==4) {cout << "Nice!";}
   else {
      cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
      goto loop;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other loop statement is `for`

Another way is to use functions - they can be called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to use a `while` or `do-while`...

```
for (;;) //same as while(true)
{
    int a; 
    cout << "What's 2+2?";
    cin >> a;
    if (a==4) 
    {
        cout << "Nice!";
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "WRONG! Try again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you should somewhere introduce a `break`-statement.

Comment: Sorry forgot about that somehow. Will fix it now @StephanLechner